# ElasticSearch - filtered query with multiple clauses ES 5

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently trying to create a query that matches multiple fields in a filter differently after switching to elastic search 5, but they do not seem to be working. This is what I think think the query should be:

```
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: [{ match: { name: 'athing' }}],
                filter: [
                    { bool: {
                        must: [
                            { term: { ownerId: 123} },
                            { term: { itemId: 3453} },
                        ]
                    }},
                    { bool: {
                        minimum_should_match: 1,
                        must: [
                            { term: { groupId: 123565} },
                            { term: { groupId: 5555} },
                        ]
                    }}
                ]
            }
        }
```

In this case, the results must match the non-analyzed item Id and group Id. In the previous code, elastic search 1.5 was used and the matching was done by a collection of 'and' and 'or' placed within the filter. This does not work anymore it seems.

I also want to make it so the query is able to get anyone with one of the passed group Id (rather than all of them). I tried to do that in the second bool query of the filter.

Ideally, I want a query that has the match 'athing', belongs to the owner ID 123 and the item ID of 3453 that is present in either group ID 123565 or 5555.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
bool:
  must: [ term: ownerId, term: itemId]
  should: [ term: groupId, term: groupId ] 
  minimum_should_match: 1
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks! One question though, from my understanding that query means that the results must at least match the must and the should. Does that mean results that matches the must but not any of the should terms can pass?